# Ionic Push works with ionic serve but not Ionic View

Tags: cordova, push-notification, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

**Summary:** 
I followed [Push from Scratch](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-from-scratch) and can successfully send a one-time push from my dashboard and receive it in my desktop browser via ionic serve, but when I switch the device token to my iOS device running Ionic View, I don't receive the one-time push. Why?

**Update:**
I also tried the [iOS Setup](http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/push-ios-setup), thinking that maybe I needed a dev certificate, after after completing those instructions, I saw the red box at the bottom that generating a development push certificate is completely unrelated to Ionic Push development mode.

**Long version:**

I followed along with all the steps on [Push from Scratch](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-from-scratch). Of note is that I installed 'ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push' as part of the instructions for using Ionic Push. Running 'ionic serve' works fine for testing the app in a desktop browser, as does 'ionic upload' to Ionic View (an iOS app for viewing/testing on-device). However, ionic emulate ios fails with this error code:

```
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    Ld build/emulator/pushit.app/pushit normal i386
(1 failure)
Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/stewart/Code/pushit/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,pushit.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,pushit,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/stewart/Code/pushit/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/stewart/Code/pushit/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
Error: /Users/stewart/Code/pushit/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2
```

I haven't been able to resolve this error yet and I don't know if it's effecting failure of Ionic Push on Ionic View.

Anyway, once I run ionic serve, I then go to my Ionic Dashboard for my app and then go to Push / Testing > One-time Notification.

There I select:

- 'Development' for the iOS Certificate
- 'Device Tokens' for Delivery Mode.
- I put in a Notification Title
- I copied the device token that logs in my desktop browser console
- I put in a Notification Message

When I send, the notification response looks something like this:

```
{"errors":[],"message_id":"047760c8bca311e58729c251c9984d2c","result":"queued"}
```

And then when I click back to the tab with my Ionic app, an alert pops up with the Notification Message, as expected.

However, when do ionic upload and then open up my app on my iOS device, and then in my browser go back to One-time Notification and change the Device Token to be the token corresponding to my iOS device, and then click send, the push notification never shows up on my device.

Any thoughts on why it's not working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

I read through the entirety of [Quick Start](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-quick-start) and found this note: "Development pushes aren't native push notifications, and are meant for testing against our API. They'll work in a browser or emulator..." This seems to indicate that dev push notifications on Ionic View don't work (and explains why the dev push notifications *do* work on the desktop browser. It would be helpful if this note was also included in the [Push from Scratch](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-from-scratch) documentation.

In the meantime, I have a separate issue of figuring out why my app fails on 'ionic emulate ios'.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue with ionic push.  I got the error message like this: 

Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/emmychen/cordova/ionic/myapp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,myapp.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,myapp,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/emmychen/cordova/ionic/myapp/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/emmychen/cordova/ionic/myapp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch


Did you find the solution yet?

Comment: @Emmy yes, sorry I didn't follow up here, but as I mentioned on the phonegap-plugin-push repo (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/570), updating Xcode and disabling bitcode worked for me. So it seems like you might need to provide a bit more detail in your comment on the repo so they can help you troubleshoot. Good luck!

Comment: thank you very much for all your help.  Ionic.io just changed their api to beta.  Then my push does not work anymore.  I really need to release this app. So I will go for my own push server (airnotifier).   I guess I will wait until ionic.io service is in the production.  Another concern I have about ionic.io service is how much they will charge the developers later.   even the good service like parse is closing.  nothing is secure.  I thing the best is to have my own service.